# Elastic Search Date Range filter for Array fields

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am looking for how to filter date range from an array. 
Sample Data looks like below

```
"airings":[{
    "startTime":"2015-08-29T10:00:00+0000",
    "endTime":"2015-08-30T21:30:00+0000"
  },{
    "startTime":"2015-08-29T10:00:00+0000",
    "endTime":"2015-08-31T21:30:00+0000"
  }]
```

Need a date range filter that search airings between a given startTime and endTime.  I have the below query, but the syntax is not correct.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": 
            {
                "airings.startTime": {
                  "gte": "2015-08-30T12:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "airings.endTime": {
                  "lte": "2015-08-30T01:00:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
     ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 128
}
```

Can anyone help to see if this date range feature is available on an array or not? Any other alternative for this kind of search? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `airings` a nested object property? Are you trying to return the parent document, or just individual inner documents (`airing`)?

Comment: I will return the parent object.  I have Title at the same level as airings.  If any of the airings are matching, then that particular title will be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "range": {
                  "airings.startTime": {
                     "gte": "2015-08-28T12:00:00.000Z"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range": {
                  "airings.endTime": {
                     "lte": "2015-08-31T01:00:00.000Z"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/8f9e747b3e3d8824ee9933b6ceb42b0f98532d28

Comment: I have a combination of title and date range search.  Once i include title, in the above filter, it fails with errors.  I added title in the above link.  Can you please help to check.  Currently without the title, i have many results returned in my data.  I don't have a way to find if all the returned records are within the date range.

Comment: Can you save your change to the sense gist code and paste the resulting link? I can't see your change otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /flights/airings
{
    "startTime":"2015-08-29T10:00:00+0000",
    "endTime":"2015-08-30T21:30:00+0000"
}

POST /flights/airings
{
    "startTime":"2015-08-29T10:00:00+0000",
    "endTime":"2015-08-31T21:30:00+0000"
}

GET /flights/airings/_search
{
   "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : { "match_all" : {}},
            "filter" : {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [{
                  "range": {
                    "startTime": {
                      "lte": "2015-08-30T12:00:00.000Z"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "endTime": {
                      "gte": "2015-08-30T01:00:00.000Z"
                    }
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you boraas.  Your answer helped as well to find match_all